# How to pass parameters to Resource from out side

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Im using Laravel Nova and i have a problem! I need to perform some  specific validation in Items Resource and i need to know its Category id.  The Items resource is nested in Category resource.
I get the Items via HasMany field like so:

```
public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [

            new Panel('Items', [
                HasMany::make('Items', 'items')
            ]),
        ];
    }
```

this is actually Category resource.

how can i know Category id inside Items resource?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If your relationship is set up as a One-to-Many (one Category has many Items) you should have the `category_id` available as a field on that model; and them model should have a `BelongsTo` relationship with the Category.

In your "Item" Nova resource define a `BelongsTo` field to access that relationship, or use the `category_id` attribute of the model directly if you need to.